# onsubmit = "function( )" on form not working

Tags: javascript

I'm doing form validation, when I call my function 'validtae( )' using 'onsbmit' in the form it doesn't work. when I click the button submit the validation that supposes to happen doesn't work I have no idea why it's not working, I tried to add return in onsubmit still not working. I tried calling the function with onfocus inside the input tag and it works but I want to work when I click the button.

```js
// getting inputs

const namee = document.forms['myForm']['name'];
const email = document.forms['myForm']['email'];
const password =document.forms['myForm']['password'];

// getting where the erroe gonna show

const nameerror = document.querySelector('#nameerror');
const emailerror = document.querySelector('#emailerror');
const passworderror = document.querySelector('#passworderror');

// validation function

function validate(){
    if(namee.value == "" ){
        namee.style.border = "2px solid red";
        nameerror.textContent ="name cannot be blank";
        namee.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(email.value == "" ){
        email.style.border = "2px solid red";
        emailerror.textContent ="email cannot be blank";
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(password.value == "" ){
        password.style.border = "2px solid red";
        passworderror.textContent ="password cannot be blank";
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
            <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
            <div id="nameerror"></div>
             <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
            <div id="emailerror"></div>
            <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Create a password" 
             required>
                <button id="submit" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: My hunch is that the browser's own validation for the `required` attribute kicks in before `onsubmit` is called. If that's not what you want then remove the `required` attribute.

Comment: IMHO, you should completely re-think your validation JS. Also, in the HTML code there     is no _passworderror_ `div`.

Comment: just add `noValidate` to your form, like this: `<form name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()" noValidate>`

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are wondering why the error message isn't shown. That's likely because the browser's *own validation* for the `required` attribute kicks in before `onsubmit` is called. I.e. `validate` isn't even called at the moment, which you can easily verify by adding a `console.log` call.

If that's not what you want then remove the `required` attributes.

```js
// getting inputs

const namee = document.forms['myForm']['name'];
const email = document.forms['myForm']['email'];
const password =document.forms['myForm']['password'];

// getting where the erroe gonna show

const nameerror = document.querySelector('#nameerror');
const emailerror = document.querySelector('#emailerror');
const passworderror = document.querySelector('#passworderror');

// validation function

function validate(){
    if(namee.value == "" ){
        namee.style.border = "2px solid red";
        nameerror.textContent ="name cannot be blank";
        namee.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(email.value == "" ){
        email.style.border = "2px solid red";
        emailerror.textContent ="email cannot be blank";
        email.focus();
        return false;
    }
    if(password.value == "" ){
        password.style.border = "2px solid red";
        passworderror.textContent ="password cannot be blank";
        password.focus();
        return false;
    }
}
```

```html
<form name="myForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validate()">
  <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name">
  <div id="nameerror"></div>
  <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email">
  <div id="emailerror"></div>
  <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Create a password" >
  <button id="submit" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
</form>
```

Alternatively just let the browser handle the validation and remove your own `validate` function.

Answer (score 0):

If any of the validation checks failed you should use `event.preventDefault()`

```js
function validate(event){
    let invalid = 0
    if (namee.value == "" ) {
        namee.style.border = "2px solid red";
        nameerror.textContent ="name cannot be blank";
        namee.focus();
        invalid++;
    }
    if (email.value == "" ){
        email.style.border = "2px solid red";
        emailerror.textContent ="email cannot be blank";
        email.focus();
        invalid++;
    }
    if (password.value == "" ){
        password.style.border = "2px solid red";
        passworderror.textContent ="password cannot be blank";
        password.focus();
        invalid++;
    }
    if (invalid > 0) {
        event.preventDefault()
        return false
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>
```

Change the submit button to input, it will work.

Comment: What's the problem with using a button?

Answer (score -1):

Check this out

```
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Name" required>
        <div id="nameerror"></div>
         <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Email" required>
        <div id="emailerror"></div>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Create a password" 
         required>
            <button onsubmit="validate()" id="submit" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
```

Comment: You are calling a function inside an html not to return the function inside it ,you have return your function in your JavaScript code above

Comment: The `submit` event is not triggered on the `button`.

Comment: Then use input tag instead of button tag